# Search terms for potatoes inside of a bun

Tags: baking, bread, potatoes

So, while traveling in Japan, I found that a lot of European-style bakeries have a dish that's essentially a baked potato inside of a bun.  Like, it's a small potato wrapped in bread dough which is pinched closed over top of it, with bacon, green onion, and cheese on top.  Now that I'm home, I'd like to recreate it.  For the life of me, however, I can't find any kind of recipe.  Since I don't remember what it was called, I'm stuck rehashing fairly generic Google searches for "baked potato in bun with cheese" or the like.  What is this dish called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you are talking about is simply a stuffed or filled bun.  They come stuffed with a wide variety of sweet and savory fillings.  Often they will be named by what they are filled with followed by the word "pan", denoting bread.

Examples can be seen [here](http://www.ragingcravings.com/2012/11/fuji-pan-japanese-bakery-haymarket/) and [here](http://www.foodgal.com/2010/09/the-most-unusual-sandwiches-ever-at-clover-bakery/)

Comment: It's quite similar to the bacon potato goro goro, yes.  I had a bit more luck searching in Japanese on cookpad, where ポテトパン (potato pan) gives good results.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a knish. It can be filled with anything but often contains seasoned mashed potatoes and is covered by dough which is then baked or fried.

Comment: Very similar to knish, yes, except the potato inside is still whole which I expect changes how it needs to be cooked.